# Draw Element's Contents onto a Canvas Element / Capture Website as image using (?) language

Tags: image, canvas, render

I asked a question on SO about compiling an image file from HTML. Michaël Witrant responded and told me about the canvas element and html5.

I'm looked on the net and SO, but i haven't found anything regarding drawing a misc element's contents onto a canvas. Is this possible?

For example, say i have a div with a background image. Is there a way to get this element and it's background image 'onto' the canvas? I ask because i found a script that allows one to save the canvas element as a PNG, but what i really want to do is save a collection of DOM elements as an image.

*EDIT*

It doesn't matter what language, if it could work, i'm willing to attempt it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, `drawWindow` only works in Firefox.

This code will only work locally and not on the internet, using drawWindow with an external element creates a security exception.

You'll have to provide us with a lot more context before we can answer anything else.

Comment: I'm trying to render a specific portion of a screen's content of a webpage as a PNG. I was told it's possible with canvas and toDataURL.

Answer (score 0):

http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/

CutyCapt is a command line utility that uses Webkit to render HTML into PNG, PDF, SVG, etc.  You would need to interface with it somehow (such as a shell_exec in PHP), but it is pretty robust.  Sites render exactly as they do in Webkit browsers.

I've not used CutyCapt specifically, but it came to me highly recommended.  And I have used a similar product called [WkHtmlToPdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/), which has been awesome in my personal experience.

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts using drawWindow parameters, that were drawing wrong parts or the element, I managed to do it with a two steps processing : first capture the whole page in a canvas, then draw a part of this canvas in another one.

This was done in a XUL extension. drawWindow will not work in other browsers, and may not work in a non-privileged context due to security reasons.

```
function nodeScreenshot(aSaveLocation, aFileName, aDocument, aCSSSelector) {
  var doc = aDocument;
  var win = doc.defaultView;
  var body = doc.body;
  var html = doc.documentElement;

  var selection = aCSSSelector
    ? Array.prototype.slice.call(doc.querySelectorAll(aCSSSelector))
    : [];

  var coords = {
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: Math.max(body.scrollWidth, body.offsetWidth, 
                      html.clientWidth, html.scrollWidth, html.offsetWidth),
    height: Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
                       html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight)

  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

  canvas.width = coords.width;
  canvas.height = coords.height;

  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  // Draw the whole page
  // coords.top and left are 0 here, I tried to pass the result of
  // getBoundingClientRect() here but drawWindow was drawing another part,
  // maybe because of a margin/padding/position ? Didn't solve it.
  context.drawWindow(win, coords.top, coords.left,
                     coords.width, coords.height, 'rgb(255,255,255)');

  if (selection.length) {
    var nodeCoords = selection[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    var tempCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var tempContext = tempCanvas.getContext("2d");

    tempCanvas.width = nodeCoords.width;
    tempCanvas.height = nodeCoords.height;
    // Draw the node part from the whole page canvas into another canvas
    // void ctx.drawImage(image, sx, sy, sLargeur, sHauteur,
                                 dx, dy, dLargeur, dHauteur)
    tempContext.drawImage(canvas,
      nodeCoords.left, nodeCoords.top, nodeCoords.width, nodeCoords.height,
      0, 0, nodeCoords.width, nodeCoords.height);

    canvas = tempCanvas;
    context = tempContext;
  }

  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.95);
  return dataURL;
}
```

Comment: This was done in a XUL extension. drawWindow will not work in other browsers, and may not work in a non-privileged context due to security reasons.